# Realm Reserved Words

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm having an issue with Realm Swift. I have an object which is suppose to store information about the user created character. However certain properties are not saving. If I switch the name of the object just by one letter it saves and reads back correctly. The first example refuses to save anything but the default value for the `race` property, but the second example saves any value to the `racea` property with no issue. What is causing this?

Example 1

```
class Character: Object {

    //MARK: Properties
    dynamic var id: Int = 1
    dynamic var name: String = "John Appleseed"
    dynamic var level: Int = 1
    dynamic var exp: Int = 0
    dynamic var race: Int = 0
    dynamic var career: Int = 0
    dynamic var currentHealth: Int = 100
    dynamic var inventory: Inventory? = Inventory()

    //MARK: Realm
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Example 2

```
class Character: Object {

    //MARK: Properties
    dynamic var id: Int = 1
    dynamic var name: String = "John Appleseed"
    dynamic var level: Int = 1
    dynamic var exp: Int = 0
    dynamic var racea: Int = 0
    dynamic var career: Int = 0
    dynamic var currentHealth: Int = 100
    dynamic var inventory: Inventory? = Inventory()

    //MARK: Realm
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Extension

```
extension Character {
    func getRace() -> String {
        return Fitventure.species[race]
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably the issue lie somewhere else on your code, this looks fine

Comment: @Tj3n I've updated the post. It seems like the `getRace()` function was causing the issue. Why does realm do this when I have a function that doesn't share the same name as the variable?

Answer (score 0):

If the `getRace()` function was causing the issue, then it sounds like to me that this might be an unfortunate collision between Swift and the Objective-C runtime reflection features that Realm uses to work.

Realm dynamically generates its own accessors for each of its properties in order to explicitly manage how data is saved and retrieved from disk. As a result, it's not possible to override the accessors of Realm properties, and doing so will create strange behavior.

Best practice is what you've already discovered: when creating another method that transforms the Realm property somehow, you need to make sure the function doesn't have a name that might have been implicitly generated by the Objective-C runtime.